# Need to validate data in parent table PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have created two tables A and B with Table A as parent table and Table B as child table having foreign key constraint with Table A.

Following are the contents of Table A

```
CUS_ID    NAME
 1       MICHAEL
 2       SANDRO
 3       ROBERT
```

Following are the contents of Table B

```
CUS_ID     ORDER
  2        PIZZA
  3        BURGER
```

I will get input data in following format to insert in to the above mentioned tables.

```
  NAME     ORDERS
 SANDRO    BURGER
 ROBERT    PIZZA
```

I am trying to create a pl/sql procedure to insert data into Table B after validating data in parent table Table A.

scenario 1: If data is available in parent table Table A and then insert data only in Table B.

scenario 2: If data is not available in Parent Table Table A, then insert NAME in to Table A and then insert ORDER data into Table B.

For scenario 2, i am able to achieve it using the following pl/sql code

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A (cus_id, name)
  VALUES (cus_seq.NEXTVAL, NAME)
  RETURNING cus_id INTO l_cus_id;

INSERT INTO TABLE_B (cus_id, order)
  VALUES (order_seq.NEXTVAL, l_cus_id, ORDER);
```

I need help in achieving scenario 1. Even I will look forward to other suggestion in achieving both the scenarios in optimum way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to encapsulate the lookup of table_a in a sub-routine.

```
create or replace procedure place_order
         ( p_name table_a.name%type
           , p_order table_b.order&type )
is
    l_cus_id table_a.cus_id%type;
    function get_cus_id 
         ( p_name table_a.name%type )
        return table_a.cus_id%type
    is
        return_value  table_a.cus_id%type; 
    begin
        begin
            select cus_id into return_value
            from table_a
            where name = p_name;
        exception
            when no_data_found then
                insert into table_a (cus_id, name)
                values (cus_seq.nextval, p+name)
                returning cus_id into return_value;
       end;
       return return_value;
    end get_cus_id;
begin
    l_cus_id  :=  get_cus_id(p_name);
    insert into table_b (cus_id, order)
    values (l_cus_id, order);
end place_order;
```

Comment: Thanks!! your solution suits me best

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach

```
  BEGIN
      SELECT cus_id INTO l_cus_id
      FROM table_a
      WHERE table_a.name = l_cust_name;
  EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
             INSERT INTO TABLE_A (cus_id, name)
             VALUES (cus_seq.NEXTVAL, l_cust_name)
             RETURNING cus_id INTO l_cus_id;
  END;
  INSERT INTO table_b (ord_id, cus_id, "ORDER")
  VALUES (order_seq.NEXTVAL, l_cus_id, l_order);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can try this

```
    CREATE or REPLACE procedure place_order
     ( p_name table_a.name%type
       , p_order table_b.order&type )
       is
       v_cnt number;
      BEGIN
         SELECT count(name) into v_cnt from  a where name=p_name;
         INSERT into table_b values(p_name,p_order);
      EXCEPTION
         when NO_DATA_FOUND
          insert into table_a values (cus_seq.nextval,p_name);
         insert into table_b values(p_name,p_order);
      END;
```

Comment: Thanks Harshit!! Your answer helped me lot